# Как наследовать методы, которые возвращают ссылку на текущий объект?

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть базовый класс

```
class LineEditItem
{
public:
    LineEditItem(QLineEdit* le, const Values_t& values = Values_t()):
        values(values),
        le(le)
    {}
    LineEditItem &addValue(int v, const QString &s)
    {
        values[v] = s;
        return *this;
    }
    LineEditItem &addValues(const Values_t& vals)
    {
        for (auto key: vals.keys())
        {
            values[key] = vals[key];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    void setValue(uint32_t v)
    {
        QString str;
        if (values.contains(v))
        {
            str = values[v];
        }
        else
        {
            str = "";
        }
        le->setText(str);
    }
    void clearValue()
    {
        le->clear();
    }

protected:
    Values_t values;
    QLineEdit* le;
};
```

Есть дочерний класс, который должен наследовать методы addValue и addValues

```
class LineEditItemBits: public LineEditItem
{
public:
    LineEditItemBits(QLineEdit* le, int begin, int end, const Values_t& values = Values_t()):
        LineEditItem(le, values),
        begin(begin),
        end(end)
    {}
    void setValue(uint32_t v)
    {
        int s = end - begin + 1;
        v = (v >> begin) & ((1 << s) - 1);
        LineEditItem::setValue(v);
    }
    LineEditItemBits &addValue(int v, const QString &s)
    {
        LineEditItem::addValue(v, s);
        return *this;
    }
    LineEditItemBits &addValues(const Values_t& vals)
    {
        LineEditItem::addValues(vals);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int begin;
    int end;
};
```

Но приходится явно прописывать эти методы и вызывать из них методы базового класса.
Как наследовать эти методы из базового класса так, чтобы они возвращали ссылку на дочерний класс?

Comment: никак - то что вы хотите сделать неверно с архитектурной точки зрения: весь смысл наследования в том, чтобы работать с объектами через базовый интерфейс. В вашем случае базовый интерфейс - это `LineEditItem`. Зачем вам возвращать ссылку на производный класс?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch в данном случае ```LineEditItemBits``` является расширением базового класса. Ссылки на себя метод возвращает, чтобы обеспечить возможность массового вызова ```item.addValues(v1).addValues(v2)```.

Comment: а что вам мешает для `item.addValues(v1).addValues(v2)` использовать базовый интерфейс?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch объекты находятся в списке ```QList<LineEditItemBits>```. ```auto l = QList<LineEditItemBits>() << LineEditItemBits().addValues(v1).addValues(v2) << LineEditItemBits().addValues(v1).addValues(v2)```.

Comment: то что вы хотите нереализуемо. Вам надо или хранить ссылки/указатели на базовый класс или использовать другой подход, например шаблоны

Comment: @goldstar_labs как здесь можно применить шаблоны?

Comment: @МатвейИссаков слушайте, ну вот а что вам мешает сначала сконструировать объект, а потом добавить его в список? Я уж даже не говорю о том, что у вас сдесь объект копируется

Comment: Есть куча вариантов несколько раз вызывать функцию. Переменное количество аргуметов `#include <stdarg.h>`. Массивы указателей `T*arg[]={&a,&b,...,nullptr}`. Список `std::list`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch так ```auto l = QList<LineEditItem*>() << (LineEditItem*)(new LineEditItemBits())->addValues(v1)->addValues(v2) << (LineEditItem*)(new LineEditItemBits())->addValues(v1)->addValues(v2)```. И чтоб addValues возвращала указатель на объект?

Comment: @МатвейИссаков это вопрос, предложение, утверждение???

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вопрос. Вы имели ввиду это, когда говорили об использовании интерфейса базового класса?

Comment: @МатвейИссаков что-то типа того

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch как тогда правильно уничтожить объекты в списке? Они должно быть синхронизированы со списком и уничтожаться вместе с ним.

Comment: @МатвейИссаков умные указатели вам в помощь